# Get video duration from URL without AVURLAsset

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming

To get video duration we create an AVURLAsset and request duration which returns CMTime which then can be converted to seconds.

But I want to do that manually without AVURLAsset.

So I started debugging the network by Charles and found it request the first two bytes of the video by setting `Range : bytes=0-1` in header.

I did the same and was able to get the bytes. But now problem is how to parse those bytes to calculate length.

I search document references and google but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Instead could you give an idea of what you want to achieve doing this ? Maybe there is a general better solution ?

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I am making a custom movie player that supports caching. I am using resourceLoaderDelegate to accomplish that with custom scheme. Now i am hitting the service to get mp4 range for seek purpose in the same AVPlayer way. AVPlayer first request two bytes in which it gets range and calculates time and then buffer using partial download. I had accomplished everything accept calculating time. Now I know passing the url to AVURLAsset will calculate the time but it makes an extra call to server. As i am already calling the server for range an extra call for time is useless